# How do I add a conditional class to elements rendered with v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a group of objects that are rendered with `v-for`.

```
    <div v-for="answer in answers" :key="answer.id" class="field has-addons">
      <p class="control">
        <button @click="addNewAnswer" class="button is-primary">
          <span class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
          </span>
          <span>Добавить</span>
        </button>
      </p>
      <p class="control">
        <input
            @input="answers[answerCount - 1].answer = $event.target.value"
            type="text"
            class="input"
        >
      </p>
    </div>
```

These are the models I use to render

```
  data() {
    return {
      answers: [
        {
          id: 0,
          answer: '',
          isEntered: false,
        }
      ],
      answerCount: 1,
    }
  },
```

And this is the code for adding a new line to enter the answer

```
addNewAnswer() {
      const newAnswer = {
        id: Date.now(),
        answer: '',
        isEntered: false,
      };
      this.answers.push(newAnswer);
      this.answers[this.answerCount - 1].isEntered = true;
      this.answerCount += 1;
    },
```

I need to add an `is-static` class to the input after adding the entered response. How do I do this correctly?

If I add this to the input element

```
:class="{ 'is-static':answers[answerCount - 1].isEntered }"
```

Then the class will not be added to the past element as it should be, because I will be referring to an already new object of the array answer. I couldn't think of any alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your problem statement, No need to manage a separate `answerCount` variable. As you are iterating answers array in the top most element. You can access it's object properties directly using dot(`.`) notation.

Suggestions **:**

- Replace `@input="answers[answerCount - 1].answer = $event.target.value"` with `v-model="answer.answer"`
- Pass `answer.id` as a param in `addNewAnswer` method and then update the property value of the passed object id.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      answers: [
        {
          id: 0,
          answer: '',
          isEntered: false,
        }
      ],
      answerCount: 1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNewAnswer(answerId) {
      const newAnswer = {
        id: Date.now(),
        answer: '',
        isEntered: false,
      };
      this.answers.push(newAnswer);
      this.answers.forEach(obj => {
        if (obj.id === answerId) {
          obj.isEntered = true;
        }
      })
    },
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.is-static {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="answer in answers" :key="answer.id" class="field has-addons">
    <p class="control" >
      <button @click="addNewAnswer(answer.id)" class="button is-primary">
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </span>
        <span>Добавить</span>
      </button>
    </p>
    <p class="control">
      <input
          v-model="answer.answer"
          type="text"
          class="input"
          :class="{ 'is-static': answer.isEntered }"
      >
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with v-model:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      answers: [
        {
          id: 0,
          answer: '',
          isEntered: false,
        }
      ],
      answerCount: 1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNewAnswer() {
      const newAnswer = {
        id: Date.now(),
        answer: '',
        isEntered: false,
      };
      this.answers.push(newAnswer);
      this.answers[this.answerCount - 1].isEntered = true;
      this.answerCount += 1;
    },
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.is-static {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="answer in answers" :key="answer.id" class="field has-addons">
    <p class="control" >
      <button @click="addNewAnswer" class="button is-primary">
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </span>
        <span>Добавить</span>
      </button>
    </p>
    <p class="control">
      <input
          v-model="answer.answer"
          type="text"
          class="input"
          :class="{ 'is-static':answer.isEntered }"
      >
    </p>
  </div>
  {{ answers }}
</div>
```